# How do I center the image upon small screen sizes (responsiveness)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

First of all, sorry for this novice question, I am just a learner in web development at the moment..

I have had some struggle for the last couple hours with my attempt to positioning the dog image (inside the iPhone frame) to the center when the screen gets shrunk (small - medium sizes) so that it looks better.

When the screen gets smaller, the image is supposed to occupy the most area in the vertical space and be exactly centered in location (while it gets to the right side upon a large screen (laptop or desktop). However, the image leans on the left side rather than being in the center on small sizes currently.

Do you guys have any idea to sort it out? I will really apprecciate your help...

My current code is:

```
  <!-- Title -->
  <section id="title" class="gradient-background">
    <div class="container col-xxl-8 px-4 py-0">
      <div class="row flex-lg-row-reverse align-items-center g-1 py-0 pt-5">
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
          <img src="./images/iphone.png" class="heading-image d-block mx-lg-auto img-fluid mt-5" alt="Bootstrap Themes" width="auto" height="200" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-body-emphasis lh-1 mt-5">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-start">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg px-4 me-md-2 mt-3"> 
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                class="bi bi-apple mb-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path 
                d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43Zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282Z" />
                <path
                d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43Zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282Z" />
              </svg>
              Download
            </button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-4 mt-3">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                class="bi bi-google-play mb-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path
                  d="M14.222 9.374c1.037-.61 1.037-2.137 0-2.748L11.528 5.04 8.32 8l3.207 2.96 2.694-1.586Zm-3.595 2.116L7.583 8.68 1.03 14.73c.201 1.029 1.36 1.61 2.303 1.055l7.294-4.295ZM1 13.396V2.603L6.846 8 1 13.396ZM1.03 1.27l6.553 6.05 3.044-2.81L3.333.215C2.39-.341 1.231.24 1.03 1.27Z" />
              </svg>
              Download
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <!-- Features -->
  <section id="features">
    <div class="row g-4 py-5 row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-3">
      <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
        <div class="icon-square text-body-emphasis bg-body-secondary d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fs-4 flex-shrink-0 me-3">
          <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#toggles2"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Featured title</h3>
          <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
            Primary button
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
        <div class="icon-square text-body-emphasis bg-body-secondary d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fs-4 flex-shrink-0 me-3">
          <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#cpu-fill"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Featured title</h3>
          <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
            Primary button
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
        <div class="icon-square text-body-emphasis bg-body-secondary d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center fs-4 flex-shrink-0 me-3">
          <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#tools"></use></svg>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Featured title</h3>
          <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
            Primary button
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the CSS code: (although the current CSS code doesn't get in the way of this problem, I believe)

```
.gradient-background {
  background: linear-gradient(300deg, #00bfff, #ff4c68, #ef8172);
  background-size: 180% 180%;
  animation: gradient-animation 18s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}
```

I tired some syntax in bootstrap like mx-auto and text-center and so on.. Nothing has worked out..

Answer (score 0):

Using the img-fluid structure for vertical images, img-thumbnail structure for horizontal images, will make the image responsive. You must specify a height and general dimensions. You must assign the height and width of the dimensions to the same class as the class where the col-lg-6 class is located.
Along with the mx auto feature. Let's talk about zanab's picture standing in the middle

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).